# How and where to add a robots.txt file to an ASP.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, robots.txt

I am using ASP.net with C#.

To increase the searchability of my site in Google, I have searched & found out that I can do it by using my robots.txt, but I really don't have any idea how to create it and where can I place my tag like `ASP.net`, `C#` in my txt file.

Also, please let me know the necessary steps to include it in my application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

robots.txt is a text file in the root folder that sets certain rules for the search robots, mainly which folders to access and what not. You can read more about it here: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: So does it mean that it is not releated to the web site ranking and popularity ?

Comment: Ranking and popularity depends upon keywords that you set in the meta for your pages and the content in the pages. If the contents does not include the keywords that you set in the meta tag, than the ranking won't work. Also, even if they match, the anking depends upon the density of the keyword in the content.

Answer (score 4):

The robots.txt file is placed at the root of your website and is used to control where search spiders are allowed to go, e.g., you may not want them in your `/js` folder. As usual, wikipedia has a great [write up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

I think you may find [SiteMaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/) more useful though.  This is an XML file which you produce representing the content of your site.  You then push this to the main search engines. Although started by Google all the main search engines have now agreed to follow a standard schema.

Increasing your Google score, and SEO in general, isn't something I've know much about.  It sounds like a black art to me :) Check out the [IIS SEO Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/03/iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit.aspx) though, it may offer some pointers.

Comment: Thanks Keith, is their any other way I can use to increase my website rank on google..  I really can't afford to buy a SEO tools. anything free out there in the market ?

Answer (score 3):

Most search engines will index your site *unless* a robots.txt tells it not to. In other words, robots.txt is generally used to *exclude* robots from your site.

Comment: What I understood is this that robot.txt will do the work for me to protect my folders & files to be accessed on internet, am I correct ?

Comment: It's not an absolute protection since it's up to the crawler to respect your robots.txt file... unlike server-based files like .htaccess on Apache which is actually *enforced* by the web server.